# how to load JPA Entities and Repositories in sprint boot app from external folder/jar

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, classloader

I would like to load/aware JPA Entities/repositories from external folder in my springboot application as my app supports dynamic generation of Entities and repositories at runtime based on customer configuraiton.
Can someone help how to achieve loadig JPA Entities/repositories from external folder ?

PS : anyone from spring community can help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You should manually configure application context.

`@EntityScan` annotation is used to tell Spring where to find entities.

`@ComponentScan` is used to create beans, as you know `@Repository` is bean.

`@EnableJpaRepositories` is used to enable JPA repositories.

So code would look something like this, you should specify package:

```java
@ComponentScan({"com.example", "com.external"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.example", "com.external"})
@EntityScan({"com.example", "com.external"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppService.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Update

If you want to load jar file, you should install it to your local maven repository using `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>`. Then you can add it to your projects pom.xml as dependency.

Comment: All the configuration is already done and it was working quite well. my question is how to load jar file which is in external folder let's say I have jar which contains dynamically generated entities and repo like EmployeeEntity and EmployeeRepository in emp.jar under c:/external-folder/emp.jar
I am looking for a way to instruct springboot to load EmployeeEntity and EmployeeRepository from the c:/external-folder so that Emplee data should in response of rest api requested

Comment: Then you should install jar file to local C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\.m2\repository using following command:
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>

After that you can add it to your pom.xml

Comment: no, spring boot running on server should pick external jar without rebuild spring boot app and deploy
Should be something that running app should be able to load external jar

Comment: Without a rebuild how are you gonna make changes to your spring boot app? And without any change how can you expect your running app to do something new? My suggestion was to load your external jar to your project on compile. I don't understand why you want to do it on runtime.

Comment: yes, without redeploying app and running app should be able to use entities/repos, if that is not possible, max I can bounce the server to pick the changes from external folder but building and redeploy is not possible.
That is the requirement, i.e ability to create fields/attributes based on customer domain instead deliver/ship via war. There are many enterprise apps support this dynamic attribute creation. similarly am trying build apps to provide flexible and powerful feature our customers.

Answer (score 0):

JAR typically defined as package file format to aggregate classes and other resources into one file to distribute aplication software/libraries/utilities on the java platform.

```
command line to run jar file: java -jar filename.jar
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but questions way beyond to you response,
looking for a way to configure external folder to load jpa entities and repo's.
if it is simple java files then class loader would help but am trying to load entities and repos which must spring aware to get the data from entity.